# php5.5 FreeBSD port apache module

Tags: php, apache, freebsd, ports

I have an issue with lang/php5(5) FreeBSD 10 port.
I need to build it with apache module, but i don't see this option in configure section. It offers only cli, cgi and fpm version, though I strictly remember that I have already built php5 with this module. Both lang/php5 and lang/php55 have this problem. Port collection is fresh (from 31 March).
I cannot run my apache without php.

P.S. My installed apache version is 2.4.

[lang/php5 port configure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17rgq.png)

Comment: Please read /usr/ports/UPDATING: PHP 5.5 Apache module is now a separate port, www/mod_php55 (www/mod_php5 for PHP 5.4)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the new www/mod_php5 port.

Comment: Thank you. Using separate port for a module is unobvious, isn't it?
Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to vote you up.

Comment: @iwakura - whether it's obvious or now, it was documented in `/usr/ports/UPDATING`, which is always the first place to check when something weird seems to be happening with your ports.

Answer (score 2):

The Apache PHP module has been separated from the main PHP port.
  If you had the APACHE OPTION selected, you have to perform the
  following steps:

1) update your lang/php* options (i.e. 'make config')
  2) rebuild lang/php* port
  3) install www/mod_php* port

It is *mandatory* to build both ports with the same DEBUG and ZTS
  options, so if you have a threaded Apache (i.e. worker or event MPM)
  you have to select the ZTS option in lang/php* port.